# Progress while deserializing JSON

Tags: json.net, progress

I'm deserializing a huge JSON (1.4 GB) via a stream, because I don't want to load the whole content into memory in advance just for parsing. That's working fine, but it takes ~80 seconds, so I want to display a progress.

```
public JObject DeserializeViaStream(string filename)
{
    object obj;
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            obj = serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader);
        }
    }
    return (JObject) obj;
}
```

I have not yet tried but only one idea: I could implement my own stream reader which keep track of the bytes being read and comparing that to the file length.

Is there a built-in option or easier way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using the idea I had. Luckily there's already a [ProgressStream available by Mel Green (archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200407110802/http://mel-green.com/2010/01/progressstream/). The [original URL](http://mel-green.com/2010/01/progressstream/) is no longer available.

Please note:

- this approach may not work for all situations and with all libraries forever. This is due to the fact that the `Seek()` operation provides random access, and someone could read the file multiple times.
- I can't post the source code here, because it was released under an unclear license.

Comment: I used the same solution and it works fine, except: although progress indicates that all bytes have been read, the process still hangs  for a long time inside `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` - and I can't figure out who is busy with what...